# Events in TypeScript for HTML5 canvas game

Tags: typescript

I'm working on a HTML5 canvas space invaders game and want to receive events in my Game.ts class from my player classes shoot method (in my gameObject module file) The Game.ts has a var called playerBullets and this needs to be updated ever time the player shoots!

```
module GameObjects {

    // Class
    export class   Player {
        color: string = "#00A";
        x: number = 50;
        y: number = 270;
        width: number = 20;
        height: number = 30;

        constructor () {
        }
        draw(canvas) {
            canvas.fillStyle = this.color;
            canvas.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        }

        shoot() {
            // Sound.play("shoot");

            var bulletPosition = this.midpoint();

            playerBullets.push(Bullet({
                speed: 5,
                x: bulletPosition.x,
                y: bulletPosition.y
            }));
        };

         midpoint() {
            return {
                x: this.x + this.width / 2,
                y: this.y + this.height / 2
            };
        };

           explode() {
            //  this.active = false;
            // Extra Credit: Add an explosion graphic and then end the game
        };

    };


}
```

and the game.ts:

```
class game {


constructor () {
}
var playerBullets: Array = new Array[40];
FPS: number = 30;
```

any ideas?

---

if I was doing this in pure js it would be easy to just make all the stuff global and not need events but that would be tough to maintain..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle it like you would in another event capable oo language (such as c#).  Create an event action in player and subscribe to it in Main.ts.

For instance add a method member in player:

```
public OnShoot: Function;
```

Then in your shoot method add this line:

```
if(OnShoot) {
    OnShoot(new Bullet({
            speed: 5,
            x: bulletPosition.x,
            y: bulletPosition.y
        }));
}
```

Then in your Main.ts, after you've created your player all you need to do is register its OnShoot.  Example:

```
var player = new GameObjects.Player();

player.OnShoot = function(bullet: Bullet) {
    playerBullets.push(bullet);
}
```

Hope this helps.

NOTE: You could always do a "true" event based implementation via event listeners (JQuery has a great setup for this) but for your implementation a subscribable function is good enough.  Plus I feel as though it's more appropriate.

Comment: and how does this bullet with the speed speed: 5, get returned from the method in the bullet class player.OnShoot = function(bullet: Bullet) {

Comment: You do if(OnShoot) in order to ensure that something has been bound to the handler, you don't want to try executing an undefined function (just good practice to check before using).

Secondly the player shoot method wouldn't return the new bullet but rather it would pass it into the OnShoot method.